# Explain XMLHttpRequest creation

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I'm learning XMLHttpRequest from w3schools. I don't understand the following snippet of code. What does `window.XMLHttpRequest` signify? What makes it true or false? Is this entire if/else structure only there to account for ie6 and ie5, and if so can it all be replaced by one line which reads `xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()` ?

```
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
     // code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
```

Comment: Before someone says it, I already did read the docs on that property of window. I did not understand. I'm seeking a plain english explanation.

Comment: after you've learned the low level stuff, considering going to a framework that takes care of the cross browser considerations for you, such as jQuery.  See jQuery ajax() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, i agree with harschware, having some cross-browser tool helps because it's a complex field.

The above code is a cross-browser code snippet that creates an `XMLHTTPRequest` object.

It is well-structured because it relies on a functionality check rather than browser checking. See this article "Feature-Detect Rather Than Browser-Detect" at:
http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/

So this:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
```

--detects whether the browser has XMLHttpRequest functionality implemented as a global function (members of window object), if so the XMLHttpRequest object is constructed that way.

Otherwise the code blindly assumes it can create the XMLHttpRequest by calling ActiveXObject functions, which is the way to create such an object in IE5 and IE6 as noted.

The last assumption might not be correct because the browser might not even have that functionality or it could be implemented in a different way. An exception could be raised on the last case.

Comment: Just coming back around three years later as a more experienced JavaScript engineer and cleaning up some formatting. Kind of fun to look back at the learning path I followed. I remember this being so confusing once upon a time. Thanks for helping me back then.

Answer (score 2):

> ### Summary
>
> `...` in `if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { ... }` is only evaluated when standard-XHR is supported. Else, ActiveX is used to support IE5-6.

To check whether the `XMLHttpRequest` API <sup>[specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest1/#toc)</sup> is supported, test whether the global `XMLHttpRequest` object exists. Since `window` is the global object, simply checking for the existance of the `window.XMLHttpRequest` property.<sup>{1}</sup>

That is illustrated below, `!` is the *logical NOT* operator, used to show the result inside `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)`.

```
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    // Supported:
    !!window.XMLHttpRequest === !![object XMLHttpRequest] === !false === true
    // Not supported, so the property does not exist, and is undefined
    !!window.XMLHttpRequest === !!undefined               === !true  === false
```

But, that's not the end of the story. The concept of XHR originates from Microsoft, who was the first to implement it in their browser, through an `ActiveXObject`: Internet Explorer 5.0. Later, in version 7.0, Microsoft added support for the standardized XHR API.

No-one cares about IE5 any more. However, there are still a significant number of IE6 users (approx 1%). So, it doesn't hurt to also support IE5-6 through:

```
... } else { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
```

---

{1}: Other methods to consider:

- `if (typeof window.XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined')` - This would also work.
- `if (XMLHttpRequest)` - **should not be used**. When the variable does not exist (=not declared), a `ReferenceError:`XMLHttpRequest is undefined` is thrown

Comment: So assuming this isn't happening in a browser; it's a PhoneGap webapp, it's safe to only write that one line of code-->  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: @Aerovistae It's safe to use `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` directly. XHR(2) is a well-supported standard (<IE6 do not support it, because these were released before XHR was standardized).

Answer (score 1):

[The story of XMLHTTP](http://www.alexhopmann.com/xmlhttp.htm) shared some interesting history about XMLHTTP and XMLHttpRequest. Long story short, XMLHTTP was introduced by Microsoft as an ActiveX object, you'll need to create it with `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` or `new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")`, see [Using the right version of MSXML in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx) for more. Later on other browser vendors found this component useful, and worked with W3C to standardize it in the name of XMLHttpRequest, which is a native object of window object, and can be instantiated with `new XMLHttpRequest()`. However, as not all browsers support XMLHttpRequest object, e.g. IE6 and IE5, a common practice is to detect if XMLHttpRequest object is a valid object of window object via `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)` - if yes, then create it with new, otherwise try fall back to XMLHTTP ActiveX. Hope this helps.